# Validate on blur or much less

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vee-validate

I am using Vee-validate 4 with Vue 3. I am trying to validate a username in the database if it exists. So, this is how I do it

Field:

```
<div>
                        <div class="relative border border-gray-500 rounded-md px-3 py-2 shadow-sm focus-within:ring-1 focus-within:ring-blue-600 focus-within:border-blue-600 ">
                            <label for="name" value="Name" class="absolute -top-2 left-2 -mt-px inline-block px-1 bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-50">Username</label>
                            <Field @keydown.space.prevent type="text" autocomplete="username" name="name" id="name" v-model="form.name" :rules="validateUsername" validateOnInput required autofocus class="bg-gray-900 text-white block w-full border-0 p-0 placeholder-gray-500 focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm" placeholder="" />
                        </div>
                        <ErrorMessage name="name" class="text-red-500 mt-2" />
                    </div>
```

call to DB:

```
const usernameIsUnique = (name) => 
    axios.post("/api/verify/checkusername", { name })
        .then(({ data }) => data)
        .catch(err => ({ // resolve with error details
        valid: err.response?.data?.valid ?? false,
        data: {
            // get the message from the response if it exists
            message: err.response?.data?.data?.message ?? "Username already registered"
        }
    }));
```

async method:

```
async validateUsername(value) {
                // if the field is empty
                if (!value) {
                    return 'This field is required';
                }
                const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]{4,20}$/i;
                if (!regex.test(value)) {
                    return 'This must be a minimum of 4 characters';
                }
                const check = await usernameIsUnique(value);
                if (check.valid) {
                    return true;
                }
                // All is good
                return check.valid || check.data.message;
            },
```

I am dealing with 2 issues

- The validator is running on every key press. In my head, it should only run on Blur
- The validator is case-sensitive. How could I make it case-insensitive?

For the second issue, Note I am doing this in Laravel in a controller. So, here is that code.

Laravel Controller

```
public function checkUsername(Request $request) {
        Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        ])->validate();
    
        return response()->json([
            'valid' => true,
            'data' => [
                'message' => 'Username is available!'
            ]
        ], 200);
    }
```

I am stumped so I could really use some guidance here.

Answer (score 0):

With that library there does not seem to be a blur method, instead you could use a debounce method

debounce is essentially running the validation after the user has stopped changing the value after a certain amount of time in this case, 1 second using the `data-vv-delay="1000"` attribute.

```
<div>
    <div class="relative border border-gray-500 rounded-md px-3 py-2 shadow-sm focus-within:ring-1 focus-within:ring-blue-600 focus-within:border-blue-600 ">
        <label for="name" value="Name" class="absolute -top-2 left-2 -mt-px inline-block px-1 bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-50">Username</label>
        <Field
            @keydown.space.prevent
            type="text"
            autocomplete="username"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            v-model="form.name"
            :rules="validateUsername"
            validateOnInput
            required
            autofocus
            class="bg-gray-900 text-white block w-full border-0 p-0 placeholder-gray-500 focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm"
            placeholder=""
            data-vv-delay="1000"
        />
    </div>
    <ErrorMessage name="name" class="text-red-500 mt-2" />
</div>
```

as for the insensitive unique validation you will have to create a new validator.

app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
...

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('iunique', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            $query = DB::table($parameters[0]);
            $column = $query->getGrammar()->wrap($parameters[1]);
            return ! $query->whereRaw("lower({$column}) = lower(?)", [$value])->count();
        });
    }
...
```

not 100% on the validation however. got this from the github https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9430#issuecomment-274482274

Comment: Unfortunately the delay does not seem to work. I did remove ValidateOnInput which did help some but its still doing the verification to the API on every keystroke. To a point im not minding that but at the same time I would like to at least "delay" it a little. 

I have not tried the rest yet.

Comment: Is validateOnBlur or validateOnChange not what you're looking for? @ArcticMediaRyan

Comment: @JakeCatron yes, it is, but it doesnt work. So what happens by the above code is once I start typing past the 3-4 character minimum it starts sending every character change to the API/Axios. Np delay, no onblur, nothing seems to stop that. I am not opposed to a couple of checks during typing but really there is no need to check until the user is done typing.

Comment: @ArcticMediaRyan https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/292#issuecomment-277908806 turns out wont work with v-model. use v-input